# How to optimize where query with enum type

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization, where-clause

I have relatively simple query:

```
 select client_coordinator_id
    from projects 
    where status not in ("DELETED", "ARCHIVED")
    and client_coordinator_id > 0
    group by client_coordinator_id
```

The projects table have about 320k records, and both **client_coordinator_id** and **status** columns have indexes, and the query still takes about 0.7 seconds.

**status** is ENUM type.

EXPLAIN gives this:

```
id - 1
select_type - SIMPLE
table - projects 
partitions - null
type - index
possible_keys - status,client_coordinator_idx,status_project_batch_id_idx,idx_status_new_status_id
key - client_coordinator_idx
key_len - 4
ref - null
rows - 311837
filtered - 40.00
Extra - using where
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any idea what is wrong with this query?

Comment: I guess you use `group by client_coordinator_id` to remove duplicates. Instead try `select distinct client_coordinator_id` and check if there is any improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> both client_coordinator_id and status columns have indexes

I would recommend an index on both columns rather than individual indexes on each column. So:

```
create index ix_projects on projects(status, client_coordinator_id)
```

This should be the right sequence of columns, but you may also give a try to:

```
create index ix_projects on projects(client_coordinator_id, status)
```

Try each index, then drop it and try the next one - don't try with both at the same time, otherwise you won't be able to tell which one helps.

It is also quite unclear why you use `group by` but no aggregeate function appears in the `select` clause. Presumably, you want `select distinct` instead. This will not necessarily improve performance, but this makes the intent clearer:

```
select distinct client_coordinator_id
from projects 
where status not in ('DELETED', 'ARCHIVED')
and client_coordinator_id > 0
```

Comment: The second index helped a lot - it went down to 0.09 seconds. Thanks a lot :). When distinct is used the query is significantly slower (it is slower than the original query). With group by it goes down to 0.09s.